# Visual studio code error 'get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient' from assembly

Tags: azure, powershell

I get the following error when trying to run any Azure related powershell code from visual studio code.

It used to work, but whilst setting up the environment I think I loaded 2 profiles, Azure RM and Azure cli. I have since disabled one but been stuck with this error ever since.

If it also helps, the environment is such that there is a proxy being used by the laptop that could be blocking things.

```
connect-azaccount : Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Clients.ResourceManager, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
At line:1 char:1
+ connect-azaccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], TypeLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeLoadException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

> Visual studio code error 'get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient' from assembly: -

*Need to check below:*

1. This kind of error arises when there is a confliction between `AzureRM` and `Az` modules. Make sure that you have uninstalled `AzureRM` modules and try connecting with Az account again.

```
Uninstall-AzureRm
Get-Module -Listavailable Az.*
```

Once it is done, update the Az modules or re-install the Az modules with the below command.

`Install-Module -Name Az -Force -AllowClobber`

[image]

2. According to the [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1299863/how-to-fix-method-get-serializationsettings-does-n), it was mentioned that there are some issues with the compatibility between`Az.Accounts` version **2.12.2**  and Vs code PowerShell extension versions. Lower the version to `Az.Accounts`  **2.12.1** and re run the script.
3. As you mentioned proxy, check if that is blocking Azure to connect with the server. If yes, change the configuration settings and execute it.
4. If still the issue persists, restart your visual studio code and try executing the command again.

You can also refer [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2490339-connect-azaccount-doesn-t-wore-in-visual-studio-code) for the same issue.